# Facebook users similarities

Tags: distance-functions, graph-theory, metric, social-network

I'm searching for a similarity metric such that given two Facebook users it returns a value that reflects how similar the two users are. The similarity metrics must take into account (at the same time) these two contributions:

1. the user profile (age, hometown, location, religion, likes, etc.)
2. the "network factor", i.e how similar two users are in relation to their network (e.g. two users sharing a lot of common friends are more similar relative to two users with few friends in common)

So I need of a *unique* metric (a unique value) that tells us how similar two users are with regard to the users profile and the network factor.

**Update:**
Maybe, to well understand the rationale behind my problem, can be useful the idea developed in this paper: [Network and Profile Based Measures for User Similarities on Social Networks](http://www.academia.edu/661025/Network_and_Profile_Based_Measures_for_User_Similarities_on_Social_Networks).
But in this work, first, it is not clear (to me) how to combine the network and the profile similarity and, second, the network similarity (due to certain reasons discussed in the paper) is not symmetric.

Comment: This could become very tricky depending on how you want to handle distance between non-identical observations. It's simple enough to say two users aged 22 and 23 are more similar to each other than to a 64-year-old user, but it's harder to say someone listing Los Angeles as a hometown or location is more similar to someone in Hollywood vs. someone in Long Beach, and harder still to say that a Seventh Day Adventist is more similar to a Lutheran than to a Catholic. How about two users who like several non-identical TV shows vs. a third who only likes books? How much info do you want to capture?

Comment: @NickStauner you are right. But i'm interested in profile similarity in this sense: when the attribute is a numeric one then calculate a sort of distance between the two values (e.g age, coordinates for location, etc). When an attribute is a categoric one (like religion, gender, etc) consider two users A and B with religion_A = Lutheran and religion_B=Catholic then the two users are different with regard to religion (I'm interested only in perfect matching/mismatching of the categorical attribute).The same rationale is behind the two users who like non-identical TV shows

Comment: @Nicola, see the paper by Miao et al (2015) http://keg.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn/jietang/publications/KBS15-Miao-et-al-Predicting%20Individual%20Retweet%20Behavior%20by%20User%20Similarity.pdf